# What does the sequence $f_n := (1+\frac{1}{3n})^n$ converge to?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I know that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ converges to $e$, but fail to manipulate the term sufficiently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $f_n^3$ and see what it converges to.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\left((1+\frac{1}{3n})^{3n}\right)^{1/3}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $$(1+\frac{1}{3n})^{3n}$$ also approaches $e$, if $n$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

we know that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(1+\frac{a}{n})^n=e^a$$
so your sequens is
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(1+\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{n})^n=???$$

Comment: "we know that...".  Actually, I think we can be pretty certain that that is precisely the one piece of information the OP does *not* know and hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all non-zero[$*$] $a$.  Requires knowing/being convinced that $\lim_{x\rightarrow b} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{ x\rightarrow b}g(x))$ if $f$ is continuous at $b$. (A basic and well known result.)

And if $a \ne 0$ that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n = \lim_{an \rightarrow \pm[**]\infty} b_n$.  (I'm not sure I've seen this explicitly stated as such, but it should be fairly obvious and easy to convince oneself.  [If worst comes to worst one can always to a $\delta$,$\frac{\epsilon}{a}$ proof.])

Soo....

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac an)^n =$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [(1 + \frac 1{\frac na})^{\frac na}]^a =$

$\lim_{am = \frac na \rightarrow \pm\infty} [(1 + \frac 1{m})^{m}]^a =$

$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} [(1 + \frac 1{m})^{m}]^a =$

$(\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac 1{m})^{m})^a =$

$=e^a$

===

[$*$]  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1 + \frac 0n)^{\frac 1n} = \lim 1 = 1 = e^0$ trivially.

[$**$]  positive infinity if $a$ is positive.  negative infinity if $a$ is negative.